# How can I store different classes in an enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum, EnumUtil, and a few classes, ChatUtil, PrefixUtil, ect. The ChatUtil and PrefixUtil classes extend the class Util. What I need is a way to store each of them inside the enum.

Example:

I have a class that needs the prefixes, so I'd call Enumutil.PREFIX_UTIL, and it'd return the PrefixUtil class.

Here is my code, which I don't think works:

```
public enum EnumUtil
{
    CHAT_UTIL(My ChatUtil classfile),
    PREFIX_UTIL(My PrefixUtil classfile);

    private final Class<? extends Util> classFile;
    private EnumUtil(Class<? extends Util> file)
    {
        this.classFile = file;
    }

    public Class get()
    {
        return this.classFile;
    }
}
```

I know for certain this does not work, because it always returns EnumUtil. Also, I need to mention I have no idea how to use an enum correctly. I've looked at many tutorials, but I have not found any for this sort of question.

Here is the actual code, all I did was replace "ChatUtil.class" (No actual quotation) with My ChatUtil class.

So it looks like the following:

CHAT_UTIL(ChatUtil.class),
PREFIX_UTIL(Prefixes.class);
Here is how I call said enum:

Prefixes prefix = EnumUtil.PREFIX_UTIL;
And here is the error I recieve:

Incompatible types: EnumUtil cannot be converted to Prefixes

EDIT:

I'll just go back to the old way, by making Util handle it. It both worked and was efficient.

Thanks for the comments and suggestions!

Comment: This looks like it ought to work, except that the parameters for the constructors need to be e.g. `MyChatUtil.class` rather than `My ChatUtil classfile`.

Comment: Any reason you don't just reference the classes directly wherever you use them? This seems like really pointless indirection.

Comment: Show us the actual code instead of "My ChatUtil classfile". That's probably where the problem is, based on what you've told us.

Comment: Only reason I can think of that would make this usefull, is if you would want to be able to change the classes of the utils, without changing it elsewhere in the code. But indeed seems kind of pointless.

Comment: That would be why. I've been changing things a lot recently. Plus, I haven't a clue about enums so I thought it'd be a good learning experience.

Comment: All I need is the ability to call the functions / variables inside the classes. The reason I wanted to store them inside an Enum is because well, first, I don't know how and I love to learn, and second, it looks like a better way to store things.

Comment: It isn't. Possibly you are looking for the Factory pattern. This isn't it. Don't do this. It won't get you where you want to go. You can't get there from here. As far as I can see, your claim that 'it always returns EnumUtil' is quite impossible.

Comment: When I go inside another class that actually uses the enum, here is what it looks like and what it says:

Prefixes prefix = EnumUtil.PREFIX_UTIL;

"Inconpatible types: EnumUtil cannot be converted to Prefixes"

Answer (score 1):

```
Prefixes prefix = EnumUtil.PREFIX_UTIL;
```

should be

```
Prefixes prefix = EnumUtil.PREFIX_UTIL.get().newInstance();
```

But it's completely pointless. You've encoded the class name at the calling site, which is what you said you're trying to avoid. You could put the newInstance() inside the get() method, but then what will it return? It will have to return Object, so you would have to write

```
Prefixes prefixes = (Prefixes)EnumUtil.PREFIX_UTIL.get();
```

which is getting worse and worse, with the class name encoded *twice* at the calling site. You may as well write

```
Prefixes prefixes = Prefixes.class.newInstance();
```

or indeed

```
Prefixes prefixes = new Prefixes();
```

just like anybody else would.

Comment: I just thought I could store all that inside of the enum, so all I have to call is EnumUtil.PREFIX_UTIL

But if not, I can revert back to how I used to do it.

Comment: You can't avoid the get() call. You don't seem to understand what enums actually are.

Comment: I don't. I had stated that at the original post, and a comment or two. Just trying to learn what I can. The more knowledge, the better.

Comment: Suppose you stop all this and post the *actual* problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Well, that was the actual problem. I was trying to find a way to call methods from an enum, E.G. Prefixes prefix = Enumutil.PREFIX_UTIL, and be able to call it's methods.

Comment: @Dudemister1999 If your idea is to return a Class so you can call its static methods, it just doesn't work that way. You cannot do, for example, `ChatUtil.class.someUtilMethod()`. Class objects are not for doing that. Even if you could do it, I don't really see what you gain from it.

Comment: @Dudemister1999 No. You agreed above that you 'wanted to be able to change the classes of the utils without changing it elsewhere in the code', although your own usage example doesn't satisfy that requirement. This sounds very like the Factory pattern to me. I suggest you look it up.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. this.classfile refers to the classfile supplied in the enum. So EnumUtil.CHAT_UTIL.get() would return 'My chatutil classfile'. However, get() would always return a Class object, which seems kind of pointless to me..

Comment: That wouldn't work, because I need it to return a class in a way that allows me to use the methods, variables, ect. inside the specified enum.

Comment: Then you're doing it completely wrong. Unless you're also planning on using Reflection, storing a Class isn't going to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this.

```
public enum EnumUtil {
    CHAT_UTIL(ChatUtil.class),
    PREFIX_UTIL(PrefixUtil.class);

    private Class<? extends Util> clazz;
    private EnumUtil(Class<? extends Util> clazz){
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
    public Class<? extends Util> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }
    public Util getUtil() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Util {

}
```

and

```
public class ChatUtil extends Util {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ChatUtil [getClass()=" + getClass() + "]";
    }

}
```

and

```
public class PrefixUtil extends Util {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PrefixUtil [getClass()=" + getClass() + "]";
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IllegalAccessException 
     * @throws InstantiationException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        System.out.println(EnumUtil.CHAT_UTIL);
        System.out.println(EnumUtil.PREFIX_UTIL);
        System.out.println(EnumUtil.CHAT_UTIL.getUtil());
        System.out.println(EnumUtil.PREFIX_UTIL.getUtil());
    }

}
```